Is there a way to override an already-defined field when making a query in Django ORM?
To better explain my question, let's consider that I have an application that supports multiple languages, let's see this code example:
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255) # kept for backward comnpatibility only
    title_en = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_fr = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

knowing that the current language is English (en - got it by using django.utils.translation.get_language), I execute this query:
SomeModel.objects.get(title="some title")

which produces this SQL query:
SELECT * FROM some_models WHERE title='some title';

However, what I'm looking for is a way to to automatically produce a query like this based on the current language without changing the ORM query above:
# when language is English:
SELECT * FROM some_models WHERE title_en='some title';

# when language is French:
SELECT * FROM some_models WHERE title_fr='some title';

I've tried using annotations but Django doesn't allow overriding a field that is already defined in the model.
Bear in mind that the solution I'm searching for needs to work with other methods like filter and values_list and so on.

This is what packages like django-parler etc. do.

I already use a package called django-modeltranslation but it doesn't seem to cover this functionality and the project is big and is generating revenue so a quick fix for the time being would be better than using a new package

@willeM_VanOnsem django-parler hasn't received any updates since April 2022. The same goes for issue replies. no replies since 2022. any other solutions? I'm using django-modeltranslation by the way.

Instead of having separate fields for each language, create a single model field to store the title and another field for language type choices (e.g., 'en' for English, 'fr' for French).
`
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import get_language
class SomeModel(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
language = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=[('english', 'English'), ('frrench', 'French')])

current_language = get_language()
SomeModel.objects.get(title_en="some title", language=current_language)
`
This approach allows scalability as you can easily add support for additional languages without modifying the model structure.
It also provides flexibility in querying, allowing you to filter, exclude, or perform other operations based on the language type.

I appreciate your solution but I don't think this solution is for the problem above. Those fields are already existing and they cannot be removed just like that because it might break the existing functionality. currently, I do "title_" + get_language() but the goal is to let the ORM automatically add the second part (that is: `_ + get_language())

Additionally, the language is set at the user level so persistence in the database is definitely not an option
